# Fatorar Solução Hackerrank - Utilizando Somente Algoritmos

Tags: array

Estou aprendendo a programar e estou fazendo os exercícios de algoritmos do hackerrank. Estou no exercicio migratory birds.

Para ter acesso ao exercício é necessário acesso com login. Como muitos não tem acesso, vou copiar e colar o exercício aqui:

> You have been asked to help study the population of birds migrating
>   across the continent. Each type of bird you are interested in will be
>   identified by an integer value. Each time a particular kind of bird is
>   spotted, its id number will be added to your array of sightings. You
>   would like to be able to find out which type of bird is most common
>   given a list of sightings.If two or more types of birds are equally
>   common, choose the type with the smallest ID number.
>
> Function Description
>
> Complete the migratoryBirds function in the editor below. It has two
>   parameters:
>
> Integer, , denoting the number of elements in the input array. Integer
>   Array, , with array elements denoting the respective type numbers of
>   each bird in the flock. The function must return an integer denoting
>   the type number of the most common bird.
>
> Raw Input Format
>
> The first line contains an integer denoting n, the number of birds
>   sighted and reported in the array .  The second line describes ar as n
>   space-separated integers representing the type numbers of each bird
>   sighted.

Pessoal,

a minha solução é essa daqui:

```
function migratoryBirds($n, $ar) { 
    $ret = [];

    for ( $i = 0 ; $i < $n ; $i++ ){        
        $frequencia = 0;
        for ( $k = 0 ; $k < $n ; $k++) { 
            if( $ar[ $i ] == $ar[ $k ] ) {
                $ret[ $ar[ $i ] ] = 1 + $frequencia;
                $frequencia++;
            }   
        }
    }
    $arrayMaiorFrequencia = $ret[ $ar[0] ];
    $menorChaveArrayMaiorFrequencia = $ar[0];

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++ ) {
        if( $ret[ $ar[$i] ] == $arrayMaiorFrequencia && $ar[$i] < $menorChaveArrayMaiorFrequencia ) {
            $menorChaveArrayMaiorFrequencia = $ar[$i];
        } elseif($ret[ $ar[$i] ] > $arrayMaiorFrequencia) {
            $arrayMaiorFrequencia = $ret[ $ar[$i] ];    
            $menorChaveArrayMaiorFrequencia = $ar[$i];
        }
    }

    return $menorChaveArrayMaiorFrequencia;
}
```

Os inputs da função são definidos pelo exercício, ou seja, $ar é um array de int e $n é o número de elementos do array.

Porém, eu quero saber se é possível fatorar esta solução? 
Observação: apesar de estar usando php, e algumas funções em php tornariam a solução muito mais fácil e rápida, **NÃO POSSO UTILIZAR NENHUMA FUNÇÃO DO PHP**, somente o conceito de algoritmos. Sendo assim, como torno a minha solução mais limpa?

Comment: Mas a solução tem de ser em php ou não ? Se for o caso é apropriado colocar essa tag na pergunta. Aproveito também para perguntar que não ficou muito claro para mim, qual o conteúdo de `$ar` ? Tem como colocar um `var_dump` de exemplo ?

Comment: @Isac, não é necessário ser em php, mas não posso usar funções. Estou utilizando php porque comecei a aprender por ela. Um var_dump($ar) seria, por exemplo, [3,4,2,5,4] e a função migratoryBirds deveria retornar 4, porque é o elemento que mais aparece (maior frequência) no array. Outro exemplo, var_dump($ar) = [5,5,5,3,3,3]. A return da função seria 3. Tendo 5 e 3 as maiores frequencias, porém frequências iguais, a função migratoryBirds deverá retornar o tipo de menor valor.

Comment: @Isac, ficou confuso o início do meu comentário.. Posso usar qualquer linguagem, mas não as funções dela, somente algoritmos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Começo por dizer que não necessita de ter 2 `for` para calcular as frequências:

```
$ret = [];

for ( $i = 0 ; $i < $n ; $i++ ){        
    $frequencia = 0;
    for ( $k = 0 ; $k < $n ; $k++) {
```

Pode muito bem faze-lo apenas com um `for` incrementando na posição que interessa, funcionando assim como um mapa. Quanto ao achar o menor, tanto o seu `if` como `else if` deveriam ter caminhos iguais facilitando o algoritmo. Como pequeno aparte para arrays normais, se não precisa de utilizar os indices especificamente, torna-se mais simples utilizar `foreach`, pois evita de ter que indexar constantemente.

Tendo em conta esses pontos que referi, e assumindo a nomenclatura das variaveis em português, para coincidir com o que tem, poderia fazer assim:

```
function migratoryBirds($n, $ar) { 
    $passaros = [];
    foreach ($ar as $passaro){
        $passaros[$passaro] = ($passaros[$passaro] ?? 0) + 1;
    }

    $maiorContagem = 0;
    $menorId = $ar[0];
    foreach ($passaros as $id => $contagem) {
        if ($contagem > $maiorContagem || ($contagem == $maiorContagem && $id < $menorId)){
            $maiorContagem = $contagem;
            $menorId = $id;
        }
    }

    return $menorId;
}
```

[Veja o código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/ZDyuDW)

Repare que nesta minha solução juntei ambos os casos de verificação de contagem maior ou contagem igual e id menor:

```
if ($contagem > $maiorContagem || ($contagem == $maiorContagem && $id < $menorId)){
```

Tornando esta parte mais simples.

Fiz a contagem inicial de frequências apenas com um `for` e servi-me do [*null coalescing operator*](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary) para ir buscar o valor que a contagem para aquele pássaro já tinha ou zero caso não existisse:

```
($passaros[$passaro] ?? 0)
```

Naturalmente poderia fazer isto de outras formas, por exemplo à custa de `isset`, se quisesse suportar versões mais antigas do php.

**Edit**:

Certamente dá para solucionar apenas com `for` e não `foreach`, apenas optei pelo `foreach` pois é mais simples e idiomático. Alterando a minha solução para fazer uso de apenas `for` para achar as frequências ficaria assim:

```
$passaros = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
    $passaros[$ar[$i]] = ($passaros[$ar[$i]] ?? 0) + 1;
}
```

De acordo com a minha solução não é possivel de utilizar um `for` simples na verificação do maior, que é o laço/ciclo seguinte, pois apenas algumas posições estão definidas.

No seu exemplo de entrada de `[5,5,5,3,3,3]` o array de contagens fica assim:

```
array(2) {
  [5]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Aqui vê que apenas a posição `3` e `5` estão atribuídas, o que significa que não posso passar pelas posições 0,1,2,etc... até ao tamanho que seria `2`.

---

Também pode fazer este primeiro `for` sem *null coalescing operator* e servindo-se de `isset`:

```
$passaros = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
    //se a contagem para este pássaro ainda não existe define como 0
    if(!isset($passaros[$a[$i]]){
        $passaros[$ar[$i]] = 0;
    }

    $passaros[$ar[$i]]++;
}
```

Comment: como poderia achar as frequencias utilizando somente um for e nao usando o foreach?

Comment: @Guilherme Editei a resposta com mais informação relativa a isso.

Comment: qual seria o comportamento dos 2 pontos de interrogação? "??" Conheço operadores ternários (  ? e : ). Qual a diferença?

Comment: @Guilherme O `??` é o *null coalescing operator* que mencionei na resposta. O que ele faz é devolver o valor da expressão (o que está antes de `??` ) caso exista, e caso não exista devolve o que tá a direita. Na [documentação oficial](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) consegue ver exemplos disso. Como exemplo simples `$a ?? 10` resulta em `$a` se `$a` existir e for diferente de nulo ou `10` caso contrário. Como nota esta funcionalidade está disponível a partir da versão 7 do php.

Answer (score 0):

@Isac,

Consegui chegar na seguinte solução, utilizando 1 for e 1 if somente

```
function migratoryBirds($n, $ar) { 
    $contagem = 0;
    $passaro = [];
    $maior = 0;
    $menorChave= 0 ;
    for($i=0; $i < $n; $i++ ){
        $passaro[$ar[$i]] = ( $passaro[ $ar[$i] ] ?? 0 ) + 1;
        if($passaro[$ar[$i]] > $maior || $passaro[$ar[$i]] == $maior && $ar[$i] < $menorChave ) {
            $maior = $passaro[$ar[$i]];
            $menorChave = $ar[$i];  
        }
    }   
    return $menorChave;
}
```